# Accessing local google datastore via shell when running datastore emulator

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using Google Datastore Emulator (which is using gRPC) and am able to do datastore operations via a Node.js application.

Is there a way to access my local datastore using a shell or browser? I am looking for something similar to `mongod` or a `GQL-browser` console.

I have tried `localhost:8172/datastore`, `localhost:8172/console` - but it didn't help.

Comment: emulator is running on 8172 port

Answer (score 0):

No, the gRPC emulator doesn't have an interface outside of the API.

The Cloud Datastore emulator that ships as part of App Engine's local emulator does have a HTTP console.

Comment: does without gRPC have an interface ?

Comment: also,  shell/browser interface is very handy for developing - is there a plan for it going ahead ?